# evaluate a condition when using syntax parse?

Tags: racket

Is there an equivalent of `#:when` from `match` for `syntax-parse`? Wasn't able to find it in the documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. It’s also called [`#:when`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-specifying.html#%28idx._%28gentag._8._%28lib._syntax%2Fscribblings%2Fsyntax..scrbl%29%29%29). It even shows up when you [search for `#:when`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=%23%3Awhen) in the documentation search.

From the docs:

> #### `#:when condition-expr`
>
> Evaluates the `condition-expr` in the context of all previous attribute
>   bindings. If the value is `#f`, the matching process backtracks. In
>   other words, `#:when` is like `#:fail-unless` without the message
>   argument.
>
> Equivalent to `#:post (~fail #:unless condition-expr #f)`.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> > (syntax-parse #'(m 5)
>     [(m x:number)
>      #:when (even? (syntax-e #'x))
>      #'x])
> m: bad syntax
>   in: (m 5)
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I only searched on http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Parsing_Syntax.html and went through the options list as I wasn't sure what to search for.